# Pronunciation of word 'caret'

Tags: pronunciation

The word [caret](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zhs/%E8%AF%8D%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AF%AD/caret?fallbackFrom=english-chinese-simplified) in dictionary pronouce `/ˈkærət/`

I ususally pronouced wrongly in  /ˈkærit/

From the literal, 'ca' gets related to 'cat'(symbol `^`likes a kitty's nose),
How can I  relate 'et' to an easy and reasonable word?

Comment: Just pronounce it like a carrot.

Comment: How about [blanket](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blanket) or [racket](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/racket)? If you are looking for a one-syllable word, that will be hard to find, because I don't think there are many (if any) one-syllable words with an unstressed vowel (schwa). It would be hard to pronounce on its own.

Comment: In many US accents, /ət/ at the end of a word is pronounced as /ɪt/. I don't think anyone will misunderstand you if you continue to pronounce it that way.

Comment: @jsheeran but if the OP did mean /i/ (stressed high front vowel) rather than /ɪ/ (lax vowel), it would sound odd if they continued to pronounce it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vowel /ə/ is a bit odd. It normally only occurs in unstressed syllables of multi-syllable words. It does sound *similar* to the vowel /ʌ/ (note that this is, ironically enough, not actually a caret!).

However, many other vowels can also turn into /ə/ in unstressed syllables, so if you were to stress the final syllable of "caret" (e.g., for emphasis), some speakers (myself included) might turn that vowel into something else, such as /ɪ/.

In terms of simple words to help you think of the difference, I'd suggest the following 3:

- **but (/ʌ/)**: this is a close, but not exact, match for /ə/. An actual /ə/ is unstressed. It would not surprise me if some speakers use an actual /ʌ/ when stressing the second syllable of "caret".
- **bit (/ɪ/)**: this is the vowel that some speakers would use if we put stress on both syllables of "caret". It doesn't sound as close to /ə/, however.
- **beat (/i/)**: this is what you want to avoid saying, in "caret", because it would sound unnatural